# The Cause of InterruptedException

Tags: java, java-me

From J2me doc we know that:

java.lang.InterruptedException Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise paused for a long time and another thread interrupts it.

The question is if it's posible to get such exception if from one thread i call Thread.Interupt() for other thread where Run() method of other thread waiting on InputStream.Read(char[]buf) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior of blocking read in response to thread interrupt is, in fact, undefined. See [this long-standing bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4250457) for details. The short of it is that sometimes you get EOF, sometimes you get IOException.

Comment: Usually you don't get anything.

Comment: NB The long standing bug was resolved in 2011: "This is no longer an issue in jdk7 because legacy interruptible I/O is disabled by default on Solaris. It was never implemented on Winodws, and not has been implemented on Linux since jdk1.3."

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no, the `java.io.*` classes do not respond to interruptions when they are blocked in read or write methods. Typically what you have to do is close the stream and then handle the `IOException` that gets thrown. I have this pattern repeated throughout my code:

```
try {
    for (;;) {
        try {
            inputStream.read(data);

            thread.join();
        }
        catch (IOException exception) {
            // If interrupted this isn't a real I/O error.
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                throw new InterruptedException();
            }
            else {
                throw exception;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (InterruptedException exception) {
}
```

Alternatively the newer `java.nio.*` classes do handle interruptions better and generate `InterruptedIOException`s when they are interrupted. Note that this exception is derived from `IOException` and not from `InterruptedException` so you will probably need two `catch` clauses to handle either type of exception, one for `InterruptedException` and one for `InterruptedIOException`. And you'll want any inner `IOException` catch clause to ignore `InterruptedIOException`s.

Comment: Unfortunately method  interrupted() not implemented in j2me

Comment: That's true, and neither in Thread.interrupt(). So where is your interrupt going to come from? What motivates the question?