# InterruptedException : what causes it?

Tags: java, interrupted-exception

There are interesting questions and answers regarding Java's [InterruptedException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html), for example [The Cause of InterruptedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561364) and [Handling InterruptedException in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344). However, none of them tells me about the possible sources of InterruptedException.

What about OS signals like SIGTERM, SIGQUIT, SIGINT? Does pressing CTRL-C on the command line produce an InterruptedException? What else?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

None of the things you list produce an `InterruptedException`.

The only thing that can interrupt a thread is a call to [`Thread#interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--). The JLS is relatively clear on the matter, from [section 17.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.3):

> **17.2.3 Interruptions**
>
> Interruption actions occur upon invocation of `Thread.interrupt`, as well as
>   methods defined to invoke it in turn, such as `ThreadGroup.interrupt`.

See [the official tutorial on interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) for some more info as well. Specifically:

> A thread sends an interrupt by invoking `interrupt` on the `Thread` object for the thread to be interrupted. For the interrupt mechanism to work correctly, the interrupted thread must support its own interruption.
>
> ...
>
> The interrupt mechanism is implemented using an internal flag known as the *interrupt status*. Invoking `Thread.interrupt` sets this flag. When a thread checks for an interrupt by invoking the static method `Thread.interrupted`, interrupt status is cleared. The non-static `isInterrupted` method, which is used by one thread to query the interrupt status of another, does not change the interrupt status flag.
>
> By convention, any method that exits by throwing an `InterruptedException` clears interrupt status when it does so. However, it's always possible that interrupt status will immediately be set again, by another thread invoking `interrupt`.

The implication is that it is an explicit flag settable only by calling `interrupt()`, rather than triggered by other unknown external events. This is further implied by the description of the exception in various methods that throw it, [for example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) (emphasis mine):

> `InterruptedException` - **if any thread has interrupted the current thread**. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.

---

The purpose of the interrupt system in general is to provide a common, well-defined framework for allowing threads to interrupt tasks (potentially time-consuming ones) in other threads. While you could implement similar functionality with explicit logic in your own application, having this well-defined mechanism allows independent classes (e.g. the JDK, other third-party code, other independent classes in your own code) to provide this functionality in a consistent way.

The many notes and "warnings" you see about handling `InterruptedException` aren't meant to imply that they can be thrown completely spontaneously, they are meant to encourage well-designed objects that can be used in contexts that are not known yet, where `interrupt()` would be presumed to work (so really, you *do* want to assume they can be thrown spontaneously if you are creating reusable objects that will be robust in future situations - i.e. you're never guaranteed that your code won't be some day used by somebody who expects interrupts to work).

For quick one-off projects you don't *really* need to worry about special handling for these exceptions as long as you know for certain that you aren't calling `interrupt()` and aren't calling something that can call `interrupt()`, but be aware of the implications of that in the long run, especially if you end up reusing that code in other contexts.