# writing synchronized method java

Tags: java

I can not understand why no thread never enters into the method wait

```
public class File {

    private boolean writing = false;

    public synchronized void write()
    { 
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        while(this.writing == true){
            System.out.println(name +" wait "); 
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        this.writing=true;
        System.out.println(name +" writing ");
        try{
            Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*3000));
        } catch( InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.writing=false;
        System.out.println(name +" writing end ");
        this.notifyAll();
    }   
}

public class M_thread extends Thread{
    File file;

    public M_thread(String name,File f){
        super(name);
        this.file=f;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            file.write();
        }
    }   
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file=new File();
        new M_thread("t1",file).start();
        new M_thread("t2",file).start();
        new M_thread("t3",file).start();    
    }
}
```

In my code as I can prevent the problem of starvation caused by the simulation method of writing with sleep ? Because if a thread is put to sleep for a long time always will never write than one that you put to sleep for a short time

Comment: I was wrong you should swap the true with the false, but it's just a logistical error code java should be corrected

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: Yes,of course..i have add it.

Comment: Off-topic: `File` is not the best name for a class, since it conflicts with a pretty commonly used built-in class (`java.io.File`).

Comment: If I'm reading this right, the "synchronized" wrapper does the "waiting" for you (literally queues up the threads), so when each thread gets context to execute the writer() function, writing is equal to false again.

Answer (score 2):

`I can not understand why no thread never enters into the method wait` Well, this is relatively easy to describe:

```
public synchronized void write() {
    // ...
}
```

This is the same as:

```
public void write() {
    synchronized(this) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That means, that only one thread with the lock `this` can enter this block. Since you're using the same instance of `File`:

```
File file=new File();
new M_thread("t1",file).start();
new M_thread("t2",file).start();
new M_thread("t3",file).start();
```

.. every Thread has the same object reference on `this`. Therefore, if one thread enters the method `write`, then the other thread have to wait until this one thread releases the lock on `this`.
And since the default value of `writing` is `false` (and the value will be reset to `false` if a thread leaves the `write` method), the loop `while(this.writing == true)` will never be entered.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of synchronization is a bit off, it is simpler than you think.

None of your threads will be in `write()` at the same time because it is `synchronized`. So, none of the extraneous wait/notify logic you have is necessary. `this.writing` will *never* be true at the start of `write()` because you set it to false just before leaving every `write()`, and since `write()` is `synchronized`, no threads are "jumping in" to the middle of it anyways. That is, no thread will ever execute `write()` during that period that `this.writing` is true.

You can get rid of all of that logic. This is sufficient, as `synchronized` already does this work for you:

```
public synchronized void write()
{ 
    String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println(name +" writing ");
    Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*3000)); 
    System.out.println(name +" writing end ");
}
```

Just declaring `write()` as `synchronized` will already cause other threads that call `write()` to wait their turn.

Note that your `sleep()` call will not throw `InterruptedException` in your example, as you never call `interrupt()` ([interruptions do not come out of nowhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856242/interruptedexception-what-causes-it/26856361#26856361)). I have left out that exception handler for simplicity. That said, if you are constructing code to be used in other situations, it's never a bad idea to make it `interrupt()`-safe, since you never know how your code will end up being used in the future (somebody may use it in a context where they expect `interrupt()` to work).